# i have a formula to calculate multiple user generated values and when i'm trying to add to values together it just concatenates the two

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add the two values together but when i do + it concatenates the two strings so how do i use parse float on a state

i've tried to do

```
this.state.shippingCharge.parseFloat()
```

but i just go an error about how this.state.shippingCharge.parseFloat() is not a function

```
this.state = {
soldPrice: '',
shippingCost: '',
shippingCharge: '',
itemCost: '',
Profit: ' ',
paypalFee: 0.30,
paypalFeePercentage: 0.029,
ebayFee: 0.1,
profitMargin: '',
paypalFeeTotal: '',
ebayFeeTotal: '',
profitColor: '',
};
}

calculateProfit = () => {
const finalValue = this.state.soldPrice + this.state.shippingCharge.parseFloat() - this.state.soldPrice *
this.state.paypalFeePercentage - this.state.paypalFee - this.state.soldPrice *
this.state.ebayFee - this.state.shippingCost - this.state.itemCost;

this.setState({ finalValue });
}
```

I'm trying to get it to be parsed as a float not a string so i can add the two numbers together instead of concatenating the strings together

```
<Text style={styles.profitResult}>
      TOTAL PROFIT:{this.state.finalValue}</Text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call parseFloat like this:

```
parseFloat(this.state.shippingCharge)
```

In order to convert empty strings to zero, you can use

```
parseFloat(this.state.shippingCharge || 0)
```

Comment: thanks i was actually just trying to figure out how to convert the empty strings you answered my question before i even asked it

Comment: i also want to use toPrecision on the final value state how do you suggest i do that

Answer (score 2):

You've implicitly cast shippingCharge as a string by your declaration. You should either change it to a number or if you want to cast it, implement a function that casts it correctly using `parseFloat()` as a built-in global Javascript function.

```
parseFloat(this.state.shippingCharge) + ...
```

or

```
this.state {
    ... 
    shippingCharge : 0.0,
    ...
}
```

Comment: i also want to use toPrecision on the final value state how do you suggest i do that

Comment: You would handle it the same way. Where ever you make the `parseFloat()` call you can make the `toPrecision()` call. `Number.parseFloat(this.state.shippingCharge).toPrecision(2)`.

It might make sense for you to create a class that holds this data and provides getter functions that performs these calculations for you, depending upon your application.